# set char array length using length of different array

Tags: java

I'm writing a program similar to hangman. I need to set the length of  an array of '-'s to the length of the word input. I've got the length of the and i've got the array i just can't figure out how to "combine them" in a manner of speaking.

```
public static char[] initializeDisplay(char[] wordToGuess) {
    int len=wordToGuess.length;
    System.out.print(len);
    char[] charArray ={ '-' };
    return charArray;
}
```

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question. When asking a question you should at least make some attempt at solving the problem. If it doesn't produce the correct output at least you tried.

Comment: This is as far as I got. All attempts to proceed further ended in compiling errors. There was no output produced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are immutable, which means that they cannot be increased or decreased in size after creation. Set the length on initialization as follows :).

```
   public static char[] initializeDisplay(char[] wordToGuess) {
       /* No need to store the length
       int len=wordToGuess.length;
       System.out.print(len);
       char[] charArray ={ '-' }; */

       // Pre-define the length at initialization 
       char[] charArray = new char[wordToGuess.length];

       // Fills the array with the char '-' 
       Arrays.fill(charArray, '-');

       return charArray;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know number of elements in the wordToGuess in advance, you can't use Array Initializer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6

You should create new char array instead and fill in each element one by one.